# In Data Factory, how do you access a property where the name contains an '@'?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Using this sample JSON list:

```
   "value": [
        {
            "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "http://anyurl1"
        },
        {
            "@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl": "http://anyurl2"
        }
    ]
```

Within Data Factory, I have a ForEach activity which is assigned to loop through each 'value', so in this case that is two loops. My question is, how do I access the value assigned to @microsoft.graph.downloadUrl? I have tried the following:

```
@item().@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl
```

But I get the following error:

*The expression 'item().@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl' is not valid: the string character '@' at position '7' is not expected.*

I understand the '@' is a problem because it denotes to Data Factory to evaluate an expression, therefore I am looking for a way to escape this character.

Comment: It should be a JSON reference, so perhaps square brackets? item().['@microsoft'].graph.downloadUrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
@item()['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Using square brackets is optimal here because the field name has `.` in it.